# Download file after ajax request doesn't work in Chrome iOS and Android

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to do an AJAX request and create download:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "urlToVerifyRights",
   ...,

    complete: function(){
       location.href = ...
   }
});
```

Seems is not working in Chrome iOS and Android but in Desktop and Safari ios works

Where is the problem ?

Comment: When you says "download", do you mean that your location.href links to a downloadable file? Have you tried to change the location.href to an alert or log to check if the problem is there?

Comment: I checked, for sure... The url is ok. I tried with small application with a simple `location.href` and it works. With ajax, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with done

```
$.ajax({
   ...
    ...
}).done(function() {
    location.href = ...
});
```

Comment: Same thing ... nothing happens, the download doesn't work

Comment: Try adding .fail too. Maybe the ajax is not working because cross-domain or something similar

Comment: I made debug using AppBuilder from Telerik and no error occur. I put an alert in `fail` and it isn't displayed on screen, so no error

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to reproduce?

Comment: Jsfiddle won't help, I created a simple application and I put on IIS server, I reproduced the issue even no error occur.

Comment: This is really weird, the browser engine is the same (webkit) so it should work the same. Are you conected to the same net? Maybe a firewall problem?

Comment: Also check if javascript is enabled in the navigators

Comment: Yes apparently use same engine but it might behaves different. The ajax is problem and I don't know how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Modify to this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "urlToVerifyRights",
   ...,

    complete: function(){
       location.href = ...
       return false;
   }
});
```

Related: [window.location.href not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300674/window-location-href-not-working)

Comment: same thing (same issue)

Comment: Sorry, I cant help more without more data. It should work fine.

Comment: You can test using `setTimeOut` for 2 seconds and make download. Same thing... on Safari works but not in Chrome iOS

Answer (score 0):

One last try, now with promises:

```
doAjax: function () {

  var deferredValue = $.Deferred(),

  $.ajax({
     url: "urlToVerifyRights",
     ...,

      complete: function(){

         deferredValue.resolve();
    }
  });

  return deferredValue.promise();

}

doAjax ()
  .then(function () {
     location.href = ...

  })
```

Comment: see my answer, I found a solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue with the following workaround:

// I mean `complete` from $.ajax

```
complete: function(){
          var $form = $("<form>");
          $form.prop("method", "POST");
          $form.prop("action", "urlToDownload");
          $form.prop("id", "test");
          $form.append($("<input type='hidden' value='aValue' name='inputName' />"));

          $("body").append($form);
          $form.submit();
}
```

and that's works. I don't know why, but works.