# Ambiguous JQuery redirection from ajax post callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

Ambiguous behavior among Firefox and Chrome.
Here is my ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "client",
    data: "{\"operationType\": \"Update\", \"body\": \"" + JSON.stringify(formAsJson).replace(/\"/g, "'") + "\"}",
    async: false,
  })
  .done(function() {
    window.location.replace("success.html");
    alert("Success");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("failure");
  });
```

**Question 1** : If alert("Success") is present, then redirection works fine in Firefox and in Chrome redirection doesn't happen but alert is shown. Explanation for this behavior.

**Question 2** : How to redirect to a page independent of browser ?

If I comment alert("Success") in done callback, the redirection doesn't work in mozilla **but while debugging using firebug, it works.**

On chrome it doesn't work anyway with or without debugger.

P.S. Checked that control goes to redirection statement in both browser using debugger.

Comment: try adding a slash before `success`. `window.location.replace("/success.html");`

Comment: Why don't you `alert` before redirection?

Comment: @Bruno adding / doesn't help.

Comment: @Alexis same behavior as mentioned in question for .replace().

Comment: @GuruprasadRao redirection is successful in mozilla only if alert is placed after redirection.

Comment: Tried `window.location.href = "success.html";`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes similar behavior as window.location.replace("success.html") i.e. works in mozilla , not in chrome. Mozilla gives no alert post redirection, chrome doesn't redirect but shows alert.

Comment: Any `console errors`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Only warning about not to use synchronous ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I found this that might help you : [window-location-href-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300674/window-location-href-not-working), 
Have you tried adding `return false;` after `window.location.replace("success.html");`

Comment: No, it doesn't help. In mozilla redirection works in real time if followed by alert.