# window.location.href does not redirect

Tags: javascript, django

my functions are as follows

```
<a onClick="check_claims(this)"  type="button" href="javascript:void(0)" redirurl="www.facebook.com" >Invite</a>



function check_claims(ele){
    var select_claims = document.getElementById('select_claims').value;
    if (select_claims == '1') {
        var result = confirm("do you wish to continue?");
         if (!result) {
                 check_email_address();
                 return;
         }
    }
         check_email_address();
         window.location.href = ele.getAttribute('redirurl');
}


function check_email_address(){
    if ('{{broker.email_address}}' == 'None') {
        console.log('this worked till here');
        window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
    }
}
```

I just added the second function `check_email_address`. the function gets called and the log gets printed but the `windows.location.href` of this function does not get evaluated and the page keeps redirecting to url mentioned in the `window.location.href` of first function.

Comment: because in javascript it will not wait for `check_email_address` to execute, and direclty next line is redirection so it will redirect from first function before second function redirection .  Also where is `select_claims` ???

Comment: i also tried replacing the `check_email_address();` line with the if condition of `check_email_address` function. That way, javascript will ideally have to execute the next line and thereby should end up redirecting to google.com but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `return false;` at the end of the handler.

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300674/window-location-href-not-working) for more details.

**EDIT:** Try this please.

```
function check_claims(ele){
    var select_claims = document.getElementById('select_claims').value;
    if (select_claims == '1') {
        var result = confirm("do you wish to continue?");
         if (!result) {
                 check_email_address();
                 return;
         }
    }
         var email_check = check_email_address();
         if (!email_check) window.location.href = ele.getAttribute('redirurl');
}


function check_email_address(){
    if ('{{broker.email_address}}' == 'None') {
        console.log('this worked till here');
        window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: return false in the second function will only end up sending the execution to the first first function