# jQuery AJAX Page Redirection Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
$.ajax({
                url: "NewUserRegistrationServlet", 
                type: "post",                   
                cache: false,
                data : "username="+username+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(pswd)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(email),
                dataType:"xml",
                timeout: 3000,
                success: function(data) {

                    var xml_node = $('ResultSet',data);
                    var status =  xml_node.find('result').text() ;
                    var result =  xml_node.find('status').text() ;

                    if( (result > 0) && (  status == 'SUCCESS') ) {
                        alert("This Statement is getting executed");
                        //window.location.replace("login.jsp"); // Not Working
                        //window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/MyProj/login.jsp'; // Not Working
                        window.open = ('login.jsp','_top'); // Not Working

                    }else{
                        $("#RegisErr").siblings("p").remove();
                        $("#RegisErr").after("<p>User Registration failed! Please Try Again.</p>");
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, text) {
                    $("#RegisErr").siblings("p").remove();
                    $("#RegisErr").after("<p>User Registration failed! Please Try Again.</p>");
                }
            });
```

> **What i am doing wrong**

1. OnSubmit -> Validation of form // Working Fine
2. If Valid -> Do Ajax Request // Working Fine
3. On Success of Ajax -> Redirect to other JSP Page // Not Woking

**EDIT**

> Screenshot Chrome Debugger
>   [image]

**Solved**

```
 windows.location = "login.jsp"
```

> Thanks Everyone for your help.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Perhaps the extension file is missing in `NewUserRegistrationServlet`...???

Comment: @PhilippM It is not redirecting login.jsp page ?

Comment: @KodeCeeper That you mentioned already, so I assume you don't get an error in the console? How did you try to debug the problem?

Comment: @PhilippM In Chrome Developer I used JavaScript Breakpoints and in those it is executing till If Condition for Success and then staying on the same page.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what is displayed _after_ the breakpoint was hit?

Comment: just type windows.location = "login.jsp"

Comment: @divyenduz It Worked ??Now it is redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your method work i.e. one of :-

```
1. window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
2. window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

The browser is still submitting the form after your code runs.
Add return false; to the handler to prevent that.

Otherwise, use just window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";

Refer to this post ( [window.location.href not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300674/window-location-href-not-working) ) for further clarification. If you still face a problem, tag me again. I will write a detailed answer for you.

This comment is the code for your solution to work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094213/1366216

Answer (score 0):

Please trim all white spaces from result. you should write following line before if block.

`if(Number(result)>0 && status.trim()==="success")`
    {

```
//do anything you want

}
```

Comment: If condition is getting executed Check EDITED Code.

Comment: Amol there is no error on console, I Used Firebug to debug. `_self` is also not working.

Comment: Do you have any pop-up blocked install. Try using following lone of code window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");