# How to open new page in new tab and redirect current page

Tags: javascript, html

New tab works good, but for some reasons current page haven't redirect (window.location from changeLocation() doesn't work)

function changeLocation() call success everytime when I click button, but location doesn't change.

Basically it seems like window.location doesn't work because of form submit (although I use target="_blank"). But if I add return false after window.location to function, I'm not able to submit form after changing location (because I'm already on another page) and also submit before changing location impossible.

Is this possible to make it works somehow? Thanks.

```js
function changeLocation (){
  window.location = "http://bing.com";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>EXAMPLE</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://google.com" target="_blank">
  <input type="text">
  <button onclick="changeLocation()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.location() not working, not opening page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094130/window-location-not-working-not-opening-page)

Comment: @Abaddon666 I saw this question, but I use target="_blank", so this page shouldn't reload, as for me.

Comment: Hum, it works in the fiddle for me.

Comment: `window.location` is an object, overwriting it with a string makes no sense. `window.location.href = ...` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil in stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: @CBroe Doesn't metter, It doesn't work even with it.

Comment: Try without any extensions enabled in the browser. Since many of the shadier "online advertisers" use this technique nowadays to try and circumvent popup blockers, it might simply be that it gets caught for that very reason.

Comment: @CBroe It isn't solution for my problem.

Comment: @CBroe Assigning to window.location is allowed and does some magic even if it's an object.

Comment: Yes, they "allowed" it in HTML5, because they know how many people get this wrong. Doesn't mean that it makes any sense though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, you need to add setTimeout to function like this.

```
function changeLocation (){
 setTimeout(function(){
  window.location = "http://bing.com";
 },200);
}
```

No ideas why, but it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>EXAMPLE</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeLocation (){
  window.location = "http://bing.com";
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://google.com" target="_blank">
  <input type="text">
  <button onclick="changeLocation()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

google.com is being loaded in the new tab and the current tab us being loaded with bing.com

Comment: Are you sure? I've created new file and trying it here, but i't only new tab with google being opened (at least in chrome)

Comment: Ok, sorry. In firefox it really works. Please edit your message and I'll able to upwote you. Was downvoted by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
Response.Write("<script> setTimeout(function(){window.location = """ + returnUrl + """;},200);window.open (""" + loginurl + """,'_blank');</script>")
```